# When did the Z - X buttons became standard?

Tags: keyboard, control, pico-8

I like platformers and I usually play them on a keyboard.

For a while in the early 2010s, there wasn't quite a standard between my platforming keyboard controls. and my settings varied between a button series of ZXC, ASD or BNM, sometimes even FGH or IOP.

Now lately, I've been mostly used to platformers that have a keyboard keybindings of "Z" to jump, and "X" to shoot, (with the arrow keys as a D-pad) and this has also become a standard in my default keyboard mapping in Game Development.

This has also become the standard in Pico-8, where changing the controls is not possible, to an annoyance to a player who is not used to playing with the Z - X controls:

> I am never going to get used to z being the jump button

This surprised me, but it also made me curious when this has become such a standard. (I may or may not have implemented a whole keybindings feature just for cases like this)

Obviously, this shouldn't be a big problem to the majority of games that allows full button mapping, and due to that, I often can't remember all games had that as default, or which ones I've remapped to the Z - X format. But it's curious how often I've played an indie game, and the button mapping was already set to Z as jump, and X to shoot, or have at least ZXC as a button series, pleasing me that I don't have to remap them.

Some examples include: Cave Story, Gato Roboto, Undertale, Several Emulators like the Visual Boy Advance and Dolphin.

It makes logical sense to me, hence why I'm surprised to hear when it's not the standard for everyone.

Comment: Who are you quoting there? Generally this site is better for answering "how-to" type questions. Questions about gaming history might get better answers on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Particulairy just one fan/friend online who likes to check out my games, but is not familiar  with the Z - X control scheme. I've not tried the Arqade section as it felt like a public place of any in-game help. But if questions like these are more welcome, then I'll probably prefer migrating it there.

Comment: It's worth asking — you can post on their Meta page to double-check whether they'd consider it on-topic. Unfortunately unlike many industries, games don't really have a centralized standards body or official standards docs devs refer to — much of it is just tacit convention. So a developer might not have any resources to answer this question not available to enthusiast players, and there are more players, with a wider view of the genre (one common complaint among devs is that gamedev leaves us with little time to play games as widely as we used to).